# undefined method `gsub', possible issue with variables

Tags: ruby

I am trying to take an input text file and insert html tags in it in a particular way. The first part of the file needs to be formatted in a different way than the second part, so what I'm trying to do is:

1. Import the file
2. Clean up the file
3. Split the file into 2 parts
4. Format part 1
5. Format part 2
6. Recombine parts 1&2 into new file

Basically I've been able to accomplish steps 1-3 & 6, but when I add in step 4, I'm having issues

Here's my code so far:

```
file_names = ['ex_poem.txt']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)

  #clean the text
  # remove extra returns
  clean_text = text.gsub(/\n(\n)+/, "\n\n")

  # remove spaces from ends of lines
  clean_text = clean_text.gsub(/ +\n/, "\n")

  # remove spaces blank lines
  clean_text = clean_text.gsub(/(?<=\n) +/, "")

  # remove returns at start of doc
  clean_text = clean_text.gsub(/\A\n*/, "")

  # remove returns at end of doc
  clean_text = clean_text.gsub(/\n*\Z/, "")

  # parse out poem section
  poem = clean_text.scan(/[\s\S]*(?=\n\n@@@)/)
  poem = poem.gsub(/\A|(?<=\n)+(?!\n)+(?!\Z)/,"<p class=\"poetry-line\">")
  #  poem = poem.gsub(/\n\n/, "\n\n\n\n\n")

  # parse out notes section
  notes = clean_text.scan(/(?<=@@@\n\n)[\s\S]*/)

  puts clean_text
  puts poem
  puts notes  
end
```

This puts out the following error:

```
poemify.2.rb:22:in `block in <main>': undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x00007f94b104c2c8> (NoMethodError)
  from poemify.2.rb:3:in `each'
  from poemify.2.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

but if I comment the line

```
poem = poem.gsub(/\A|(?<=\n)+(?!\n)+(?!\Z)/,"<p class=\"poetry-line\">")
```

then the script runs fine. This confuses me, because I use `.gsub` earlier in the script with my `clean_text` variable and it works fine, but when I use it with the `poem` variable it doesn't work. But `puts poem` actually works fine when the offending line is commented out.

I suspect that I don't understand something very basic with the way I need to initialize variables or something, but I'm stuck.

**UPDATE:**

After being shown how `.scan` was turning `poem` into an array, I reworked the regex so that I could use `.gsub`, so `poem` and `notes` would be a string, and I could keep working with `.gsub` in a way that I understand:

`poem = clean_text.gsub(/\n(?=@@@\n\n)[\s\S]*/, "")`

`notes = clean_text.gsub(/[\s\S]*(?<=\n\n@@@\n\n)/, "")`

Comment: Welcome to SO - see my answer below.

Comment: Quick performance thing: use `gsub!` instead of `gsub` whenever possible. Your code creates a ton of unnecessary strings, because `gsub` makes a new string, where `gsub!` modifies an existing string. So if you remove the `clean_text = ` from most of your lines and add a `!` to 6 method calls, you can save yourself 6 string allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poem` holds the results of a `scan`, which returns an `Array`, not a `String`.

You can see docs here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan

`gsub` can't be called on an `Array`. You could `map` over the `Array` and call `gsub` on each element.

If your scan results contain groups you will need to `map` over each element of the initial `map`, it will contain an `Array` of `Array`s.

Also, if there are no matches, you will still receive an empty `Array`.